# How to take stereo images using single camera?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

I want to find the depth map for stereo images.At present i am working on the internet image,I want to take stereo images so that i can work on it by my own.How to take best stereo images without much noise.I have single camera.IS it necessary to do rectification?How much distance must be kept between the cameras?

Comment: You might be able to get two images with a single camera using mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood your problem correclty - will try anyway

I guess your currently working with images from [middlebury](http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/) or something similar. If you want to use similar algorithms you have to rectify your images because they are based on the assumption that corresponding pixels are on the same line in all images. If you actually want depth images (!= disparity images) you also need to get the camera extrinsics.

Your setup should have two cameras and you have to make sure that they don't change there relative position/orientation - otherwise your rectification will break apart. In the first step you have to calibrate your system to get intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters. For that you can either use some tool or roll your own with (for example) OpenCV ([calib-module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)). Print out a calibration board to calibrate your system. Afterwards you can take images and use the calibration to rectify the images.

Regarding color-noise:
You could make your aperture very small and use high exposure times. In my own opinion this is useless because real world situations have to deal with such things anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there are plenty of stereo images on the internet that are already rectified. If you want to take your own stereo images you have to follow these three steps:

- The relationship between distance to the object z (mm) and disparity in pixels D is inverse: z=fb/D, where f is focal length in pixels and b is camera separation in mm. Select b such that you have at least several pixels of disparity;
- If you know camera intrinsic matrix and compensated for radial distortions you still have to rectify your images in order to ensure that matches are located in the same row. For this you need to find  a fundamental matrix, recover essential matrix, apply rectifying homographies and update your intrinsic camera parameters... or use stereo pairs from the Internet.
- The low level of noise in the camera image is helped by brightly illuminated scenes, large aperture, large pixel size, etc.; however, depending on your set up you still can end up with a very noisy disparity map. The way to reduce this noise is to trade-off with accuracy and use larger correlation windows. Another way to clean up a disparity map is to use various validation techniques such as
- error validation;
- uniqueness validation or back-and-force validation
- blob-noise supression, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience:
-I did the rectification, so I had to obtain the fundamental matrix, and this may not be correct with some image pairs.
-Better resolution of your camera is better for the matching, I use OpenCV and it has an implementation of BRISK descriptor, it was useful for me.
-Try to cover the same area and try not to do unnecessary rotations.
-Once you understand the Theory, OpenCV is a good friend. Here is some result, but I am still working on it:

Depth map:
[image]

Rectified images:
[image]